# Getting list of member names with background task

Tags: discord.py

I have a few loops that I run with my bot to reset certain stats with a loop but recently it seems like something has changed where they are not working anymore. I can grab them with a command via on_message but not with the background task. I've tried multiple things but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
async def getmem():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        guild = client.get_guild(id=1234567890)
        if guild:
            for member in guild.members:
                if not member.bot:
                    print(member.name)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

client.loop.create_task(getmem())
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @Nurqm no error :(.  I've removed `if guild:` to see if that was holding it up and still nothing. I tried adding `channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)` and then `await channel.send('test')` below to see if it would send the message and that works in the loop but it still didn't retrieve the guild member names. Was something changed? It was working a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last week Discord changed its policy on the gateways, so now you need to enable the GUILD_MEMBERS privileged intent from your bot's control panel.  If that switch is disabled you need to message Discord support and ask them to whitelist your bot for that privileged intent.  (Same thing goes for GUILD_PRESENCES, though your particular code sample doesn't need that intent.)  Also make sure you've upgraded discord.py to 1.5 or later, because you'll need to specify intents when you use the new gateway.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
```

Here's their announcement about the change:
https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994-Gateway-Update-FAQ

Comment: thank you! I just realized this after researching for a day lol. I answered but then scrolled down and seen you had already answered. Thanks again!